# Mail sent using PHP mail not showing up

Tags: php, email, debian, sendmail

I am using PHP 5.4.35-0+deb7u2 on Debian 7.0.  I use the following PHP code to send a message.

```
    $to = $emailAddress;
    $subject = "Registration";
    $message = "Dear " . $firstname . " " . $lastName .",\n\n" .
        "Thank you for registering for our program.\n\n" .
        "To complete your registration, please confirm your registration using the following activation code.\n\n" .
        $randomActivationCode . "\n\n" . 
        "at the following link.\n\n" . $Link . "\n\n" .
        "If you did not register for our program, please accept our apologies and disregard this message\n\n" .
        "Have a wonderful day!\nCompany name.\n";

    $from = "me@yahoo.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    $mailDelivery=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if ($mailDelivery)
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location.href="http://home.com/Prewelcome.php";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Thank you for your interest in our program.\nTo complete your registration, please check your email.");
        document.location.href="Subscriptions.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Mail delivery failed");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

I get the alert box "Thank you for your interest in our program.\nTo complete your registration, please check your email." but the email never shows up.  (I am using my email address as the recipient.)

I also edited php.ini and made sure that

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

was included and that /usr/sbin/sendmail exists.  After doing this, I also restarted apache with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I also did the following test

```
sendmail me@gmail.com
```

from the command line and the mail did show up in my mail box.

I also ran

```
sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

and there were no errors.

However the mail I send from my php file never shows up in my mail box.

Comment: Did you check your `junk` folder? Edit: you can not use ...@yahoo.com on your from part without smtp authentication on yahoo server. That is why gmail blocks your basic php mail. Try phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Comment: Sorry .  I meant to mention that I checked my spam folder but there is nothing there.  Thanks,

Comment: And what about `/var/mail/root|user`? Or `/var/spool/mail/user`?

Comment: PLEASE, man, dont do this in javascript, thats horrible and mad, use `header('Location: yourlocation.php?done');` (or `?fail`, but not JS ...)

Comment: Thank you, HddnTHA and  Bas van Dorst.  /var/spool/mail/www-data contained the reason. "Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not
    accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact
    administrator of yahoo.com domain if 550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail.
    Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to
    learn about DMARC 550 5.7.1 initiative. q8si18262537qco.8 - gsmtp"

Comment: The email shows up when I change the from address but perhaps this is not that secure.  I will look into phpmailer.  Thanks again,